# Query multiple JSONB columns for an element

Tags: postgresql, query

I have a dynamically generated materialized view in this form:

```
{
    "f1": {
        "student_attempt": [
            41,
            1
        ],
        "Registration No": "E021-01-059/2014",
        "s_name": "Jone",
        "Other Names": "Doe Ng'ang'a",
        "EEE2103": {
            "grade": "F",
            "total": 20,
            "stage_id": 2,
            "cohort_id": 2,
            "session_id": 3,
            "academic_yr_id": 9,
            "level_of_study_id": 1
        },
        "EEE2110": {
            "grade": "B",
            "total": 66.67,
            "stage_id": 2,
            "cohort_id": 2,
            "session_id": 3,
            "academic_yr_id": 9,
            "level_of_study_id": 1
        },
        "EME2101": {
            "grade": "D",
            "total": 45,
            "stage_id": 1,
            "cohort_id": 2,
            "session_id": 1,
            "academic_yr_id": 9,
            "level_of_study_id": 1
        },
        "EME2102": {
            "grade": "D",
            "total": 41,
            "stage_id": 1,
            "cohort_id": 2,
            "session_id": 1,
            "academic_yr_id": 9,
            "level_of_study_id": 1
        },
        "EME2113": null,

        "SMA2173": null,
        "SMA2181": null,
        "SPH2170": null,
        "SPH2171": null,
        "{1,1}": {
            "level_rule_id": null,
            "stage_rule_id": null,
            "total_level_marks": 377.75,
            "average_level_marks": 47.22,
            "level_recommendation": null,
            "stage_recommendation": null
        },
        "{2,1}": {
            "level_rule_id": null,
            "stage_rule_id": null,
            "total_level_marks": 0,
            "average_level_marks": 0,
            "level_recommendation": null,
            "stage_recommendation": null
        },
        "{2,2}": {
            "level_rule_id": null,
            "stage_rule_id": null,
            "total_level_marks": 0,
            "average_level_marks": 0,
            "level_recommendation": null,
            "stage_recommendation": null
        }
    }
}
```

I want to search the entire table jsonb columns as follows

```
select * from mytable where 'all jsonb columns' have grade='F'
```

How can i do this if this is even possible?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your contribution/participation. Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (Help Centre)_. Currently your question is missing a full explanation (missing details) and might be closed as [**unclear what you're asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Please [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/217541/edit) your question and add more details.(e.g. table DDL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to convert your data column to `text` and search that:

```
SELECT data
FROM mytable
WHERE data::text like '%"grade": "F"%'
```

Comment: It works..Thank you...I' pretty new to POSTGRESQL...really appreciate